# State/Province Field - Searching drop down menu with keyboard

Tags: upgrade, search, addresses

Recently upgraded from 4.6.17 to 5.11.

My staff uses the keyboard to search and select from the drop down menu in the "State/Province" field when entering data. Before the upgrade, the keyboard stroke would search the first letter - could type "N" three times &v select New Hampshire, 6 times for NY, etc.

After the upgrade, this same search works differently. Instead of the first letter, it's finding any "N", in any position in a word - type one "N" & selects American Samoa, type 2 "N" for Conn... staff greatly prefers how the search worked before. Is this an easy fix?